# How to register ASP.net v4 on windows7 home basic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

which command do I run to register ASP.net v4 on windows7 home basic. I tried using **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -iru** but my options does not include **"aspnet_regiis -iru"** rather I only have **"aspnet_regiis.exe"** even thou I can see it under help but it does not allow me to type it. I am using Win 7 Home basic.

Comment: What happened when you type `aspnet_regiis -iru` in the command prompt? Did you get an error or something?

Comment: Perfect! It's done. I was using Tab key for auto complete. Thank U. @Darin Dimitrov. I even wanted to show U a snapshot of the screen but I don't know how to upload it.

Comment: I have posted this as an answer so that you can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct command, you just need to type it in the command prompt:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis -iru
```

If you wanted to use Intellisense it will append `.exe` but it is equivalent:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319>aspnet_regiis.exe -iru
```